# Encrypting and Decrypting anchor tag query string in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I have read a lot of articles on how to encrypt and decrypt query string but can't seems to find any on how to use it in html tag. This is what i'm trying to achieve
 The product id is an interger but i don't want to send it to the SingleProduct.aspx page like that. I want to encrypt it and then decrypt it on the page to make it of it for other operation

```
<a href="Singleproduct.aspx?Product=<%#Eval("Product_Id")) %>">
```

Comment: Check out Mad Kristensen's article on HttpModule for query string encryption (http://madskristensen.net/post/httpmodule-for-query-string-encryption).

Answer (score 1):

i use user's id (Session["UserId"]) as my encrypt key. ref [RijndaelManaged Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) 

 productlist.aspx like

```
<a href="Singleproduct.aspx?enProduct=<%#EncodeId(Eval("id")) %>">En Product Detail</a>
```

productlist.aspx.cs like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserId"] = "rainmaker";
}

protected string EncodeId(object id)
{
    var encryptKey = (string)Session["UserId"];
    var encryptKeyArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptKey);
    Array.Resize(ref encryptKeyArray, 16);
    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(Convert.ToString(id), encryptKeyArray, encryptKeyArray);
    string encryptedStr = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
    return encryptedStr;
}
```

Singleproduct.aspx.cs Decrypt by Session["UserId"]

```
var enProductId = Request.QueryString["enProduct"];
if (enProductId != null)
{
    var encryptKey = (string)Session["UserId"];
    var encryptKeyArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptKey);
    Array.Resize(ref encryptKeyArray, 16);
    var encryptedArray = Convert.FromBase64String(enProductId.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+')); 
    // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
    string id = DecryptStringFromBytes(encryptedArray, encryptKeyArray, encryptKeyArray);
    Response.Write(id);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a GUID field for link to detail id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there no way i can use this in my anchor html tags?

Comment: what about encrypt id after get product data?